# Minutes and Seconds regEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate minutes:seconds input where minutes can be 07 or 7.

I can get 07:35 validated using below but not 7:35. When I process the input I can append a zero if values is less than 9 but want to be able to let users type 7:35 as well.

```
^([0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may make the first munite digit optional:

```
^[0-5]?\d:[0-5]\d$
      ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM7NHi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-5]?` - an optional (1 or 0 repetitions) of a `0` to `5` digit
- `\d` - any 1 digit
- `:` - a `:` char
- `[0-5]` - a digit from `0` to `5`
- `\d` - any 1 digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, I was adding the ? before [0-5] instead of after it. Works fine now.

Comment: @NoBullMan You may add this detail to the question, BTW. A `?` at the start of the pattern will cause an exception as the start of string cannot be quantified.